# Redirect all url of domain to index.html for app engine flex env deployed website

Tags: html, google-app-engine, deployment, web, yaml

I am starting to build my product website today.
I followed some tutorials on web which teach how to deploy static website on Google App Engine.
And it's successfully deployed.

However, when I tried to customize the URLs to the index.html, the index.html file is broken by directly point to the index.html location.

My successful website: [Link Here](https://kokitang.com/6Hats)
[image: Prove image]

Failed situation: [Link Here](https://kokitang.com/6Hats/)
[image: Prove image]

My app.yaml file:
[image: App.yaml]

The different between two situations is just the last character "/" of the URL.
I have no idea why the index.html will break with the "/". The redirect handler should be redirecting to the same file location...

---

### Update:

After many times of testing. I found that the problem is about the runtime environment in app.yaml.
My website work great when env: flex.
And it breaks when env: (anything static other than flex)
So, there's two way I can go:

1. use flex env. but I don't know how to redirect to index.html since I found that -handlers is not work in flex env after my trying.
2. Keep static env to route easily. But the problem is how to make the website keeps good.

Please help...

---

### 2nd Update

After rebuild and deploy everything. 
My website is work now.
However, it's only works on https://koki-6hats.appspot.com/index.html

For other cases like:

https://koki-6hats.appspot.com/index

https://koki-6hats.appspot.com/

https://koki-6hats.appspot.com/shouldGoToIndex.html

is not worked.
How can I config the routing rule to make sure all links above can redirect to index.html automatically?

---

### 3rd update

Thanks for Alex and GAEfans answer my question!

This is my current app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

default_expiration: "3m"

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  mime_type: text/cache-manifest
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))

- url: /(.*\.atom)
  mime_type: application/atom+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.atom)

- url: /(.*\.crx)
  mime_type: application/x-chrome-extension
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.crx)

- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)

- url: /(.*\.eot)
  mime_type: application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.eot)

- url: /(.*\.htc)
  mime_type: text/x-component
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.htc)

- url: /(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.html)

- url: /(.*\.ico)
  mime_type: image/x-icon
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ico)

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

- url: /(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.json)

- url: /(.*\.m4v)
  mime_type: video/m4v
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.m4v)

- url: /(.*\.mp4)
  mime_type: video/mp4
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.mp4)

- url: /(.*\.(ogg|oga))
  mime_type: audio/ogg
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(ogg|oga))

- url: /(.*\.ogv)
  mime_type: video/ogg
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ogv)

- url: /(.*\.otf)
  mime_type: font/opentype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.otf)

- url: /(.*\.rss)
  mime_type: application/rss+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.rss)

- url: /(.*\.safariextz)
  mime_type: application/octet-stream
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.safariextz)

- url: /(.*\.(svg|svgz))
  mime_type: images/svg+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(svg|svgz))

- url: /(.*\.swf)
  mime_type: application/x-shockwave-flash
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.swf)

- url: /(.*\.ttf)
  mime_type: font/truetype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ttf)

- url: /(.*\.txt)
  mime_type: text/plain
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.txt)

- url: /(.*\.unity3d)
  mime_type: application/vnd.unity
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.unity3d)

- url: /(.*\.webm)
  mime_type: video/webm
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.webm)

- url: /(.*\.webp)
  mime_type: image/webp
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.webp)

- url: /(.*\.woff)
  mime_type: application/x-font-woff
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.woff)

- url: /(.*\.xml)
  mime_type: application/xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xml)

- url: /(.*\.xpi)
  mime_type: application/x-xpinstall
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xpi)

# image files
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

# audio files
- url: /(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))  

# windows files
- url: /(.*\.(doc|exe|ppt|rtf|xls))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(doc|exe|ppt|rtf|xls))

# compressed files
- url: /(.*\.(bz2|gz|rar|tar|tgz|zip))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bz2|gz|rar|tar|tgz|zip))

# index files
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
```

And this is my folder structure:

```
.root
  - app.yaml
  - static
    - index.html
    - favicon.ico
    - styles.html
    - php
      - sendMail.php
    - css
      - ...
    - js
      - ...
    - fonts
      - ...
    - image
      - ...
```

This build fixed the 2nd updates issue!
However,

For other cases like:

https://koki-6hats.appspot.com/index/

https://koki-6hats.appspot.com/index/index.html

is still not worked.

---

My desire final output is for example:

**Folder structure:**

```
.root
  - app.yaml
  - static
    - index.html
    - favicon.ico
    - styles.html
    - php
      - sendMail.php
    - css
      - ...
    - js
      - ...
    - fonts
      - ...
    - image
      - ...
    - folderA
      - index.html
      - css, js, etc...
    - folderB
      - index.html
      - css, js, etc...
```

**Url Relationship:**

1. URL: http://domain/folderA/(anything_and_level_behind), output: Show folderA's index.html
2. URL: http://domain/folderB/(anything_and_level_behind), output: Show folderB's index.html
3. URL: http://domain/other_folder_have_no_index_html_inside/, output: Show static's index.html
4. URL: http://domain/anything(no_/_AtLast), output: Show static's index.html
5. URL: http://domain/anything/anything/anything/(and_so_on...), which 'anything' is not 'folderA' / 'folderB', output: Show static's index.html
6. Show static's index.html when not match above cases

---

### Last update

Thanks for Alex & GAEfans help again.

Now the redirection is works perfectly. But it shows some warnings in the console of the deployed version.
[image: Warnings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that app engine is now returning `index.html` for every request

For example if you go here: https://kokitang.com/6Hats/main.css you'll see that it still returns `index.html`

This is due line 17 in your `app.yaml`

**Edit**

Ok I think I understand what you are trying to do now.

The main issue with having every link route to `index.html` is that there ARE other files you need to load like `main.css`, `main.js`, etc.

So you just need to setup a special rule for them

```
handlers:

# images, css, js, etc
- url: /(.*\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg|jpeg))
  static_files: 6Hats/\1

# all other links load index.html
- url:/(.*)$
  static_files: 6Hats/index.html
```

**2nd Edit**

You need to change your resource links to be absolute instead of relative

[image]

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">`

needs to be

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css">`

Comment: Thank you for your answering. And sorry for my bad explanation. Actually this is the result I want, but I don’t know why while it always return index.html and the website is broken when the url having “/“ at the last. You can see my attached images for the differences.

Comment: Uhhh, `https://kokitang.com/6Hats` and `https://kokitang.com/6Hats/` look exactly the same to me. Both look like your "Failed situation" screenshot. I think maybe you're seeing cached data from your browser or ISP. Try incognito mode.

Comment: So the new issue is why it’s always showing failed situation but not the successful one...

Comment: I tried and it works!!

But here is one more case need to be handle...

Since, it only works on that format like koki-6hats.appspot.com/[anything] if I put a "/" or more at behind, like koki-6hats.appspot.com/index or koki-6hats.appspot.com/index/test, it's still not work. Can u please update to handle this case also? :)

Comment: You need to change all your `<link>` and `<script>` to use absolute links instead of relative ones, updated my answer again

Comment: It works!!!

And the last thing is I getting some warning about the fonts.

Let me update my answer and provide you screen cap.

Comment: its the same issue as before. you need a handlers entry for the `.map` file type

Comment: oops, I meant you need a handlers entry for the `.woff2` file type. I don't think the warning about `.map` is super important

Comment: Although I still not fixed the warning, my redirect issue is fixed. So, I will accept your answer as correct answer. And again, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

How would the url handler ever get past line 17?  `(.*)` means "zero or more characters".  That means ANYTHING entered goes to `index.html`

The commented out lines are closer to what you want:

```
- url: /   # first test for root url
  static_files: 6Hats/index.html
  upload: 6Hats/index.html

- url: /(.*)   #everything else ends up here
  static_files: 6Hats/\1
  upload: 6Hats/(.*)
```

**UPDATE**:

I would put all of your static file directories in a `static` folder.  Then use:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: 6Hats/static

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: 6Hats/favicon.ico
  upload: 6Hats/favicon.ico

- url: /.*   #everything else after slash ends up here
  static_files: 6Hats/index.html
  upload: 6Hats/index.html
```

Change your urls for static files to format: `/static/js/filename.js`, `/static/css/filename.css`, etc.

If you lead with a catch-all pointing to `index.html`, that means all your calls to your static files (images, js, css) will also call `index.html`.  Of course, that is a mess.

**UPDATE 2:**

If you use:

```
- url: .*   #everything else ends up here
  static_files: 6Hats/index.html
  upload: 6Hats/index.html
```

(without the slash), everything else should get caught there.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. And sorry for my bad explanation. Actually this is the result I want at this moment (every url redirect to index.html), but I don’t know why while it always return index.html and the website is broken when the url having “/“ at the last. You can see my attached images for the differences.

Comment: However, it only works on that format like https://koki-6hats.appspot.com/[anything]

if I put a "/" or more at behind, like https://koki-6hats.appspot.com/index/ or https://koki-6hats.appspot.com/index/test, it's still not work. Can u please update to handle this case also? :)